# Размер скачанной части файла WebClient

Tags: c#

Есть задача, скачать ~3000 файлов с web сервера с отображением прогресса выполнения (общий и текущий размер файлов). То есть для удобства пользователей нужно реализовать общий размер файлов и сколько скачано всего (пример: *100мб из 300мб скачано*).

Общий размер загружаемых файлов получаю в виде JSON данных с сервера (он выдает список с информацией о каждом файле, его размер, имя и др.), а вот с текущим размером возникли трудности...

Я использую `WebClinet`, у которого отлавливаю событие `DownloadProgressChanged`. Внутри этого события мы можем получить `BytesReceived`, то есть тот размер, сколько мы уже скачали от этого файла, он постоянно растет, пока не станет = полному размеру файла.

Моя задача, это высчитать сколько было скачано байт за один вызов события `DownloadProgressChanged`, а не общее. Пытался сохранять предыдущее `BytesReceived` в отдельную переменную (`oldSize`) и далее делать что то вроде `var size = e.BytesReceived - oldSize;`, но в итоге, при подсчете я теряю байты, примерно половину (из 2088 файлов (~10гб) я в конце получаю: 5938728608 байт из 11561291193 (то есть почти половина, но все файлы получены успешно! Неверный идет подсчет...).

Прошу, помогите в реализации грамотного вывода скачанных байт с сервера...

---

Текущий вариант реализации:

```
private void RepairClient()
{
    var filesBlock = new BufferBlock<FileViewModel>();
    var generateOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
        BoundedCapacity = 100
    };

    var downloadBlock = new ActionBlock<FileViewModel>(async file =>
    {
        SetFileName(file.Name);
        var packPach = file.Name + ServerData.PackName;
        var uri = new Uri(main.UpdaterViewModel.Path, packPach);
        var fullPackPach = Model.StorageModel.ExpandRelativeName(packPach);
        await file.DownloadFile(uri, fullPackPach, main);
    }, generateOptions);


    var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
    filesBlock.LinkTo(downloadBlock, linkOptions);

    var totalSize = UpdateFiles.Sum(x => x.FileSize);

    SetMinMax(0, UpdateFiles.Count);
    SetSize(total: totalSize); //Вывести в интерфейс полный размер.
    SetMinMax(0, totalSize); //Работа с ProgressBar (задать min и max).
    SetStatus(true);

    UpdateFiles.ForEach(x => filesBlock.Post(x));
    filesBlock.Complete();
    downloadBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
```

Метод пытался написать с использованием простого `acync`, сейчас играюсь с `Dataflow`, но безрезультатно. В блоке `downloadBlock` делаем обычную подготовку (вычисляем пути) и вызываем метод `DownloadFile` текущего файла.

Метод `DownloadFile`:

```
public async Task DownloadFile(Uri uri, string path, MainViewModel main)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            long prev = 0;
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var diff = args.BytesReceived - prev;
                main.Progress.Size += diff;
                prev = args.BytesReceived;

                Console.WriteLine($"[{path}]: BytesReceived: {args.BytesReceived} (diff: {diff})");
            };

            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            if (dir != null && !Directory.Exists(dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

А вот вывод результата:

```
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 10215 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 3370 (diff: -2738)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 11584 (diff: 9583)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 2001 (diff: 2001)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 6108 (diff: 6108)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 8846 (diff: 8846)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 4739 (diff: -6845)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 12953 (diff: 8214)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 7477 (diff: -5476)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 14322 (diff: 6845)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 15691 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 17060 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 18429 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 19798 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 21167 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 22536 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 23905 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 25274 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 26643 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 28012 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 29381 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 30750 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 32031 (diff: 1281)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 33400 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 34769 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 36138 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 37507 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 38876 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 40245 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 41614 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 42983 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 44352 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 45721 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 47090 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 48459 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 49828 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 51197 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 52566 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 53935 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 55304 (diff: 1369)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 59533 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 63762 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 64799 (diff: 1037)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 69028 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 73257 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 77486 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 81715 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 85944 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 90173 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 94402 (diff: 4229)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 95819 (diff: 1417)
[patchw32.dll.client]: BytesReceived: 95819 (diff: 0)
[L2text\help_battle_shot.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 1067 (diff: 1067)
[L2text\help_battle_shot.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 1067 (diff: 1067)
[L2text\help_item_symbol.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 936 (diff: 936)
[L2text\help_item_symbol.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 936 (diff: 936)
[L2text\help_option_video.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 2337 (diff: 2337)
[L2text\help_option_video.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 2337 (diff: 2337)
[L2text\credit_us_03.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 907 (diff: 907)
[L2text\credit_us_03.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 907 (diff: 907)
[L2text\pet_help_quest_2.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 809 (diff: 809)
[L2text\pet_help_quest_2.htm.client]: BytesReceived: 809 (diff: 809)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 1992 (diff: 1992)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 3361 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 4730 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 6099 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 10206 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 11575 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 7468 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 8837 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 14313 (diff: 2738)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 12944 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 15682 (diff: 2738)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 17051 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 18420 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 19789 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 21158 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 22527 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 23896 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 25265 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 26634 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 28003 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 29372 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 30741 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 31384 (diff: 643)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 32753 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 34122 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 35491 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 36860 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 38229 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 39598 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 40967 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 42336 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 43705 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 45074 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 46443 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 47812 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 49181 (diff: 1369)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 53410 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 57639 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 61868 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 64152 (diff: 2284)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 68381 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 72610 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 76839 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 81068 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 85297 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 89526 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 93755 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 96920 (diff: 3165)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 101149 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 105378 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 109607 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 113836 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 118065 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 122294 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 126523 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 129688 (diff: 3165)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 133917 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 138146 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 142375 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 146604 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 150833 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 155062 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 159291 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 162456 (diff: 3165)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 166685 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 170914 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 175143 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 179372 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 183601 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 187830 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 192059 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 195224 (diff: 3165)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 199453 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 203682 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 207911 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 212140 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 227992 (diff: 15852)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 244376 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 260760 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 277144 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 293528 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 309912 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 326296 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 342680 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 359064 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 375448 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 3483 (diff: 3483)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 7712 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 11941 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 16170 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 20399 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 24628 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 28857 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 31383 (diff: 2526)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 391832 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 35612 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 39841 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 44070 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 48299 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 408216 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 52528 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 56757 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 60986 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 64151 (diff: 3165)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 68380 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 72609 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 76838 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 81067 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 424600 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 440984 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 85296 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 89525 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 93754 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 96919 (diff: 3165)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 101148 (diff: 4229)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 105377 (diff: 4229)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 457368 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 473752 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 121761 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 129687 (diff: 7926)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 490136 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 146071 (diff: 16384)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 501222 (diff: 11086)
[music\S09_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 501222 (diff: 0)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 162455 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 178839 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 195223 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 211607 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 227991 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 244375 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 260759 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 277143 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 293527 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 309911 (diff: 16384)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 313342 (diff: 3431)
[music\sc08_f.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 313342 (diff: 0)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 15638 (diff: 15638)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 32022 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 48406 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 64790 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 81174 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 97558 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 113942 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 130326 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 146710 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 162459 (diff: 15749)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 178843 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 195227 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 211611 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 227995 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 244379 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 260763 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 277147 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 293531 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 309915 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 326299 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 342683 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 359067 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 375451 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 391835 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 408219 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 424603 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 440987 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 457371 (diff: 16384)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 469073 (diff: 11702)
[music\SSQ05_F.ogg.client]: BytesReceived: 469073 (diff: 11702)
[StaticMeshes\Aden_castle_door_S.usx.client]: BytesReceived: 3614 (diff: 3614)
[StaticMeshes\Aden_castle_door_S.usx.client]: BytesReceived: 3614 (diff: 3614)
```

Можно заметить, что Diff не всегда доходит до 0, а иногда и вовсе уходит в минус...

Comment: У Вас есть возможность предоставить текущую реализацию, чтобы я смог детальней протестировать и отладить ситуацию?

Comment: А на одном файле правильно считает?

Comment: @Zergatul и с одним и с кучей, все попадаю на те же грабли..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предполагаю, что вы в обработчике события помимо вычислений (и что важно ДО вычислений) производите какие-либо операции.

Например следующий код сначала производит вычисления (надо мало времени для этого), потом вызывает вывод на консоль (файл качается рандомный с интернета)

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var sum = 0L;
    long prev = 0;

    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var diff = args.BytesReceived - prev;
        sum += diff;
        prev = args.BytesReceived;

        Console.WriteLine($"BytesReceived: {args.BytesReceived} (diff: {diff})");
    };

    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
        new Uri("http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip"),
        @"D:\temp\sample");

    Console.WriteLine($"SUM :{sum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Bytes should be: {new FileInfo(@"D:\temp\sample").Length}");
}
```

Вывод при этом корректный:

```
BytesReceived: 65536 (diff: 65536)
BytesReceived: 118414 (diff: 52878)
BytesReceived: 146814 (diff: 28400)
BytesReceived: 151074 (diff: 4260)
BytesReceived: 216610 (diff: 65536)
BytesReceived: 219234 (diff: 2624)
BytesReceived: 230594 (diff: 11360)
BytesReceived: 270354 (diff: 39760)
BytesReceived: 322894 (diff: 52540)
BytesReceived: 331414 (diff: 8520)
BytesReceived: 334886 (diff: 3472)
BytesReceived: 349874 (diff: 14988)
BytesReceived: 382534 (diff: 32660)
BytesReceived: 386794 (diff: 4260)
BytesReceived: 436494 (diff: 49700)
BytesReceived: 445014 (diff: 8520)
BytesReceived: 448486 (diff: 3472)
BytesReceived: 469154 (diff: 20668)
BytesReceived: 501814 (diff: 32660)
BytesReceived: 514594 (diff: 12780)
BytesReceived: 558614 (diff: 44020)
BytesReceived: 561454 (diff: 2840)
BytesReceived: 621094 (diff: 59640)
BytesReceived: 622514 (diff: 1420)
BytesReceived: 688050 (diff: 65536)
BytesReceived: 711974 (diff: 23924)
BytesReceived: 746054 (diff: 34080)
BytesReceived: 761674 (diff: 15620)
BytesReceived: 804274 (diff: 42600)
BytesReceived: 807114 (diff: 2840)
BytesReceived: 863914 (diff: 56800)
BytesReceived: 866400 (diff: 2486)
BytesReceived: 866400 (diff: 0)
SUM :866400
Bytes should be: 866400
```

Но, стоит нам поменять вывод на консоль с вычислениями местами (то есть поставить вначале медленную операцию)

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var sum = 0L;
    long prev = 0;

    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {   
        var diff = args.BytesReceived - prev;
        Console.WriteLine($"BytesReceived: {args.BytesReceived} (diff: {diff})");

        sum += diff;
        prev = args.BytesReceived;

        //Console.WriteLine($"BytesReceived: {args.BytesReceived} (diff: {diff})");
    };

    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
        new Uri("http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip"),
        @"D:\temp\sample");

    Console.WriteLine($"SUM :{sum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Bytes should be: {new FileInfo(@"D:\temp\sample").Length}");
}
```

То при этом, во время вывода на консоль параллельный поток может посчитать новый diff до того, как обновится prev предыдущим обработчиком (то есть для 2 diff будет использован дин и тот же prev), из за чего происходит рассинхрон. Вывод при этом:

```
BytesReceived: 16962 (diff: 16962)
BytesReceived: 25482 (diff: 25482)
BytesReceived: 28954 (diff: 3472)
BytesReceived: 45362 (diff: 16408)
BytesReceived: 62402 (diff: 17040)
BytesReceived: 63822 (diff: 1420)
BytesReceived: 83702 (diff: 19880)
BytesReceived: 82282 (diff: 18460)
BytesReceived: 103582 (diff: 21300)
BytesReceived: 104002 (diff: 21720)
BytesReceived: 125302 (diff: 21300)
BytesReceived: 145182 (diff: 19880)
BytesReceived: 146602 (diff: 1420)
BytesReceived: 148022 (diff: 1420)
BytesReceived: 172162 (diff: 24140)
BytesReceived: 173634 (diff: 25612)
BytesReceived: 194934 (diff: 21300)
BytesReceived: 203454 (diff: 29820)
BytesReceived: 221914 (diff: 18460)
BytesReceived: 223334 (diff: 1420)
BytesReceived: 235798 (diff: 12464)
BytesReceived: 265618 (diff: 29820)
BytesReceived: 271298 (diff: 5680)
BytesReceived: 306798 (diff: 35500)
BytesReceived: 309638 (diff: 2840)
BytesReceived: 347978 (diff: 38340)
BytesReceived: 349398 (diff: 1420)
BytesReceived: 390578 (diff: 41180)
BytesReceived: 393418 (diff: 2840)
BytesReceived: 431758 (diff: 38340)
BytesReceived: 439014 (diff: 7256)
BytesReceived: 474514 (diff: 35500)
BytesReceived: 486978 (diff: 12464)
BytesReceived: 533838 (diff: 46860)
BytesReceived: 538098 (diff: 4260)
BytesReceived: 587798 (diff: 49700)
BytesReceived: 592846 (diff: 5048)
BytesReceived: 638286 (diff: 45440)
BytesReceived: 652170 (diff: 13884)
BytesReceived: 707550 (diff: 55380)
BytesReceived: 716070 (diff: 8520)
BytesReceived: 748730 (diff: 32660)
BytesReceived: 762930 (diff: 14200)
BytesReceived: 828250 (diff: 65320)
BytesReceived: 833930 (diff: 71000)
BytesReceived: 866400 (diff: 32470)
BytesReceived: 866400 (diff: 0)
SUM :1035302
Bytes should be: 866400
```

Отсюда совет - в многопоточном варианте важные и быстрые вычисления помещайте в начало, значения для вывода юзеру запоминайте в локальных переменных (чтобы иъ не могли изменить параллельные потоки). Если это все равно приводит к рассинхрону, то используйте конструкции синхронизации потоков. Например, при потенциальных 2 конкурирующих потоках можно поставить `lock`

```
        lock (this)
        {
            var diff = args.BytesReceived - prev;
            Console.WriteLine($"BytesReceived: {args.BytesReceived} (diff: {diff})");

            sum += diff;
            prev = args.BytesReceived;
        }
```

Но если у вас конкурирующих потоков много, то тогда надо думать основательней. Мне, например, в голову приходят многопоточные очереди, dataflow и прочие вещи. Но это уже тяжелая арта.

И, кстати, я не уверен, что есть вообще какие то гарантии, что эти события идут в хронологическом порядке. Мне кажется поэтому они и не присылают сами дельту, а присылают просто количество скаченных данных.

Comment: Попытался я поиграться с dataflow (реализацию предоставил выше), пробовал lock, но все безрезультатно. Уже раз 15 переписываю эту часть приложения ))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так у вас вызовы идут не по порядку. Зачем вы вообще считаете что то, если новое значение меньше предыдущего? Если было скачано 100 байт, то все события, что меньше или равно 100 байт, надо игнорировать - они бесполезные и только добавляют рассинхрон.

Comment: Хорошо, добавил `if (args.BytesReceived <= prev) return;` (что по сути отсеяло все это), результат стал [чище](https://hastebin.com/uqizejunul.md), но все так же не до получаю где то байты (104.86/198.78 кб).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как вы так добавили, если на выходе у вас до сих пор вперемешку идут числа? Lock не ставили?

Comment: C lock примерно тот же [результат](https://hastebin.com/obidiwekoh.md), переписанный метод сейчас примерно [такой](https://hastebin.com/dudayahiro.cs).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ покажите вывод в консоль что получаете + значение суммы и какой она должна быть

Comment: @EvgeniyZ по идее у вас сейчас должна быть строго возрастающая последовательность от 0 до размера файла в которой вы считаете разность смежных элементов. Сумма разностей полюбому должна совпадать со скаченным контентом, или вы просто не получаете событий когда файл скачался полностью

Comment: Тьфу ты, дальше уже моя невнимательность пошла. Спасибо вам большое! lock и фильтрация значений ниже помогло.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пожалуйста. Хорошо, что завелось :)