# C# WebClient не поддерживает параллельные операции ввода-вывода

Tags: c#, webclient

Нужно поместить реализацию метода `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` в цикл for для отражения в ProgressBar-е, но при вызове метода из цикла появляется исключение - "WebClient не поддерживает параллельные операции ввода-вывода." Причем даже в цикле While, который проверяет булевое значение переменной. Без цикла работает исправно. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
     public void Download(DataEntity entity, string pathFile)
    {
        string result = entity.Url.Substring(entity.Url.IndexOf("src/") + 14);
        string fileName = pathFile + @"\" + result;

        using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            while (doWork == true)
            {
                webclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(entity.Url), fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: зачем что то проверять в веб клиенте, [подписывайтесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867290/179763) на нужное [событие](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged?view=netframework-4.8) и все дела

Comment: @tym32167 я знаю про события DownloadFileCompleted и DownloadProgressChanged, но все же интересна механика, из за чего блокируется метод из цикла.

Comment: чтобы это понять, надо увидеть ваш код

Comment: @tym32167 добавил в тело вопроса

Comment: дак вы не ждете окончания предыдущей загрузки, вы просто в цикле бесконечно пытаетесь загрузить одни и те же данные.

Comment: Забудьте об этом классе, и используйте нормальный `HttpClient`. Через него выкачивайте данные, это отнимет у вас немного больше времени на реализацию загрузки, но вы получите более эффективный код, и помимо этого сможете управлять процессом загрузки, т.е. приостанавливать, продолжать, разбивать загрузку на части, и многое другое. Из ремарков к классу: `We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.`.

Comment: @tym32167 да, уже понял, что цикл замкнут, т.к. whilte всегда true

Comment: @LLENN спасибо за совет

Comment: @LLENN Если мне не изменяет память, то HttpClient вроде не поддерживает отчет о прогрессе.