# C# прогресс нескольких загрузок

Tags: c#, async-await, progress-bar

Разрабатываемая программа должна уметь асинхронно скачивать до трех картинок включительно. Все работает на WebClient. 
Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы текущее значение прогресса в прогрессбаре подстраивалось под текущее количество закачек.

Comment: На каждую закачку - свой прогрессбар.

Comment: сделайте переменную, в которую будут "собираться" данные по прогрессу каждой закачки и значение этой переменной "скармливайте" прогрессбару

Comment: Среднее арифметическое берите

Comment: Ну 3 раза по 100 это будет 300% максимальный прогресс. То есть если первый файл у вас скачался на 15%, второй на 65%, третий на 10%, то в сумме вы на прогрессе `100*(15+65+10)/300`

Comment: как я могу получить эти три значения (15, 65 и 10) ? Обработчики событий прописаны в методе только один раз, где я могу получить доступ к e.RecievedBytes

Comment: @VanyaBelyaev вот как можно получить значения https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173322/5965412

Answer (score 3):

*Я как то делал для себя нечто подобное, код как некий черновик, так что часть косяков мог и не заметить.*

- Создадим новый класс, назовем его к примеру `DownloadManager`.
- В него добавляем необходимые свойства. Я для удобства добавлю коллекцию ссылок, текущий размер и общий размер:

  ```
  public List<string> DownloadLinks { get; } = new List<string>();
  public long CurrentSize { get; private set; }
  public long TotalSize { get; private set; }
  ```
- Далее реализуем события:

  - Создадим класс, который будет содержать в себе информацию об изменении прогрессии загрузки всех файлов. Я назвал его просто, `DownloadManagerEventArgs`:

    ```
    class DownloadManagerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadManagerEventArgs(long current, long total)
        {
            CurrentSize = current;
            TotalSize = total;
        }
        public long CurrentSize { get; }
        public long TotalSize { get; }
        public double Percent => 100 * CurrentSize / TotalSize;
    }
    ```
  - Далее добавим в класс `DownloadManager` два события. Первое произойдет при изменении прогресса, а второе при окончании загрузки:

    ```
    public event EventHandler<DownloadManagerEventArgs> OnDownload;
    public event Action OnDownloadCompleated;
    ```
- Теперь реализуем метод, который добавит ссылку в коллекцию. Я для удобства реализую два метода (один для добавления одной ссылки, а другой для целой коллекции), также я напишу их по принципу так называемых "Цепочных методов":

  ```
  public DownloadManager Add(string link)
  {
      DownloadLinks.Add(link);
      return this;
  }

  public DownloadManager Add(string[] links)
  {
      DownloadLinks.AddRange(links);
      return this;
  }
  ```
- Также нам нужен метод, который посчитает общий размер загружаемых файлов. Сделать это можно путем чтения заголовка `Content-Length`. К сожалению метод не 100%, но хоть что то:

  ```
  private async Task<long> GetTotalSizeTask()
  {
      long result = 0;

      foreach(var link in DownloadLinks)
      {
          var req = WebRequest.Create(link);
          req.Method = "HEAD";
          using(WebResponse resp = await req.GetResponseAsync())
          {
              if(long.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out long ContentLength))
                  result += ContentLength;
          }
      }

      return result;
  }
  ```
- Также я лично для себя набросал небольшой метод, который из ссылки возьмем имя файла с его расширением. Вам наверно нужно будет что то другое придумать.:

  ```
  private string GetFileNameFromUrl(string url)
  {
      Uri uri = new Uri(url);
      return Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
  }
  ```
- Хорошо, теперь самое главное. Нам нужна задача (`Task`), которая возьмет ссылку и путь и с этими данными начнет загрузку файла:

  ```
  private async Task DownloadTask(string url, string path)
  {
      using(var client = new WebClient())
      {
          long prev = 0;
          client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, a) =>
          {
              lock(this)
              {
                  if(a.BytesReceived <= prev) return;
                  var diff = a.BytesReceived - prev;
                  CurrentSize += diff;
                  prev = a.BytesReceived;
                  OnDownload?.Invoke(this, new DownloadManagerEventArgs(CurrentSize, TotalSize));
              }
          };

          await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, path);
      }
  }
  ```

  Тут мы используем `WebClient()`, у которого подписываемся на событие `DownloadProgressChanged` и реализуем его внутри `Task`. Внутри обработчика события мы отсекаем все отрицательные значения загруженных байтов, высчитываем сколько именно мы скачали от текущего файла байт (прибавляя это значение нашему свойству `CurrentSize`), ну и вызываем событие с нужными нам данными. До такой реализации я дошел благодаря [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867290) ответу.
- Имея задачу загрузки файла, мы можем смело делать главный метод загрузки всех файлов:

  ```
  public async Task Download()
  {
      TotalSize = await GetTotalSizeTask();
      await Task.WhenAll(DownloadLinks.Select(x => DownloadTask(x, GetFileNameFromUrl(x))).ToArray());
      OnDownloadCompleated?.Invoke();
  }
  ```

  Тут особо пояснять нечего, просто вызываем `GetTotalSizeTask()`, который посчитает нам общий размер всех файлов и занесет в свойство. Дальше мы преобразуем все `string` ссылки в `Task`, которые с помощью `Task.WhenAll()` будем ожидать полного завершения. В конце всех действий мы оповестим кого надо с помощью события `OnDownloadCompleated`.

Вот собственно и все. Мы сделали класс, который отвечает полностью за загрузку неограниченного числа файлов, асинхронно. Давайте использовать его:

```
var manager = new DownloadManager();

manager.OnDownload += Manager_OnDownload;
manager.OnDownloadCompleated += () => MessageBox.Show("Загрузка завершена!");

await manager.Add("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/peshchera_temnyj_ushchele_150108_1920x1080.jpg")
             .Add(new[]
             {
                 "https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/tkan_tekstura_belyj_150101_5472x3648.jpg",
                 "https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/chashka_kofe_ruka_150110_4642x2922.jpg",
                 "https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/fraktal_plamennyj_iarkij_150047_3200x2134.jpg"
             })
             .Add("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin")
             .Download();
```

Ну и обработчик простенький сделаем, который просто выведет результат в `ProgressBar` и в окно отладки:

```
private void Manager_OnDownload(object sender, DownloadManagerEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = (int)e.Percent;
    Debug.WriteLine($"{e.CurrentSize}/{e.TotalSize} [{e.Percent}%]");
}
```

[image: Result]